# Custom sql for Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

A bit of background...

I'm trying to create a custom auth backend and extend the user model.  I'm using the following as a blue print:

[blog post by Scott Barnham](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/)

For whatever reason, the ORM is generating invalid sql.  It seems to want to do a inner join back to itself and it's failing because it can't find a field named user_ptr_id for the join.

If you do a search for this, it seems that I might not be the only one.  And there is actually a reference to this in a comment on the blog post above.  But, I can't seem to fix it.

It seems like I should be able to override the SQL that is getting generated.  Is that correct?  From what I can tell, it seem like I might do this with a custom Object manager.  Correct?

However, I can't seem to find a good example of what I want to do.  Everything that I see is wanting to inherit and chain them.  That's not really what I want to do.  I sort of just want to say something like:

hey Django!  on a select, use this SQL statement.  etc

Is this possible?  Maybe my "googlin'" is off today, but I can't seem to find it.  That leads me to believe I'm using wrong terms or something.

Please note:  I'm using Django 1.3.1 with Python 2.6.5 and PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: Your best bet to obtain help is to show the code you're working with (the model(s), the code that produces the error, and the verbatim error message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David,

Yes, you can override the behavior of a model by implementing an overriding Manager in the object. I found a great blog by Greg Allard on [A Django Model Manager for Soft Deleting Records](http://codespatter.com/2009/07/01/django-model-manager-soft-delete-how-to-customize-admin/) which runs through a soft delete, to set a field `deleted` to True/False and only show objects that are not deleted, or all with deleted objects.

With that in mind, I would think you could override your object's all(), or filter() methods to get what you want. As an aside, everytime I have used a pointer, "ptr" is evident in the name of the field, it is because of class inheritance. For example, `class Animal():...`, `class Man(Animal):` Man extends or is a subclass of Animal. In the database, the Man table will have an animal_ptr_id which "extends" the animal table's tuple with that id as a Man with ANIMAL fields and MAN fields JOINed.